# ios I want to access an object in MainViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uisearchbar

I used this line from the sample project AppPrefs:

```
UITableView *tableView = ((UITableViewController *)self.navController.visibleViewController).tableView;
```

and it works of course perfectly,

so I tried:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = (UIViewController *)mySearchBar;
```

but I get warning that `mySearchBar` is undeclared, even it is a property and initialized in MainViewController (which is of class UIViewController).

I need to access various objects in MainViewController from AppDelegate, so the app could refresh itself whenever the settings is changed.

Comment: There are two cases for your App delegate to access the objects in MainViewController. 1 - Your app delegate owns the MainViewController controller - as an instance variable 2 - MainViewController is a singleton. In either case, it looks like you need to consider a re-architecture for your project. If you need to have MainViewController make changes when the settings change, look into NSNotification center, which won't need you to deal with the app delegate

Comment: @K Thanks for informative comment. I use NSNotification, but I think I use it wrongly. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch, your code is wrong at as much places as possible. Let me explain where:

One. You're casting `mySearchBar` to `UIViewController *` then assign it to a different pointer type (of type `UISearchBar *`).

Two. If you're writing this from the app delegate, how come the compiler should know which class' (even further, which object's) property are you using? There may be multiple objects/classes with a property of the same name.

I feel you're confusing typecasting and accessing properties (so I strongly recommend learning plain C correctly before digging straight into iOS development as this is such a basic question that you will likely produce low-quality code if you don't yet understand this). You should maintain an instance of your view controller (either make it a global variable, a singleton, or even better, a property of the application delegate object) and acces it from there. Example:

```
UISearchBar *bar = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] mainViewController] searchBar];
```

Comment: Additionally, your app delegate should not need to know anything about your MainViewController. Making the app delegate dependent upon your view controllers will only lead to the dark side.

Comment: @kubi absolutely right - but this question already hurts, I'm tired explaining good practice to beginners who even fail to distinguish between casting and accessors.

Comment: Thanks. However, I get warning ` warning: '-mainViewController' not found in protocol(s)` and ` warning: no '-mainViewController' method found`

Comment: @wagashi you saw the word 'Example'?

Comment: @H Thanks for informative answer. I see. I put navController (instead of mainViewController) which is of class UINavigationController as a property of the application delegate object. However, I still get warning. PS. I will study about typecasting and accessing properties.

Comment: @wagashi if your property is named navController, then you're obviously no good  with mainViewController, as in the (blindly written) example. Change the accessors to the actual names of your properties and all should be fine.

Comment: @H Hi again. Please be patient with me. Please explain what do you mean with your comment. MainViewController is own class (separate file) which is of UIViewController class, whereas navController that is of UINavigationController class is a property in xxxAppDelegate.h. I don´t have any view controller in xxxAppDelegate... Should I have one?

Comment: If you wanna access it, then you should.

Comment: In `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` I have  `MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];`, but I still get warning that `'-mainViewController' not found in protocol(s)` and `warning: no '-mainViewController' method found` when I use your code example. What does it mean?

Comment: @wagashi it means you were still not able to declare and synthesize that one poor property holding your view controller...

Answer (score 0):

If "mySearchBar" its a property declared in your MainViewController, and your self.navController.visibleController is an instance of MainViewController. Just access it like this:

```
UISearchBar* searchBar= self.navController.visibleController.mySearchBar
```

Now you are trying to assign something that doesn't even exist in your AppDelegate, because mySearchBar has not been declared in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks. I get warning for this : `error: request for member 'visibleController' in something not a structure or union`